# Create instance of a class as a static variable

Tags: python, class, variables, static

I want to create an instance of a class as a static variable of the class.

For example:

```
class Complex:
    I = Complex(0, 1)
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

When I do that, I get `NameError: name 'Complex' is not defined`. How can I do that?

Comment: The name isn't available during the definition of the class. You'd have to do it after the class definition is complete, `Complex.I = Complex(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try call outside

```
class Complex:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
I = Complex(0, 1)
```

`__init__`אין לך סיבה לקרוא לאותו קלאס, כיוון שהקלאס אוטומטית מריץ את ה

You have no reason to call the class inside, because the class automatically runs the `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

Try to instance the class after the class definition:

```
class Complex: 

  def __init__(self, x, y): 
     self.x = x 
     self.y = y
I = Complex(0, 1)
```